# gpg-agent refuses SSH keys with ssh-add reporting "agent refused operation"

Tags: openssh, ssh-agent, gpg-agent

I'm using openssh7.5p1 and gnupg 2.1.21 on arch linux (these are the default versions that come with arch).  I would like to use `gpg-agent` as an ssh agent.  I put the following in my `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`:

```
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-qt
enable-ssh-support
```

Arch automatically starts a gpg-agent from systemd, so I set

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh"
```

When I run `ssh-add -l`, it reports no identities and `ps` reports a `gpg-agent --supervised` process as I would expect.

Unfortunately, when I run `ssh-add`, no matter what the key type, it doesn't work.  Here is an example of how I tried dsa:

```
$ ssh-keygen -f testkey -t dsa -N ''
Generating public/private dsa key pair.
Your identification has been saved in testkey.
Your public key has been saved in testkey.pub.
$ ssh-add testkey
Could not add identity "testkey": agent refused operation
```

All other gpg functions work properly (encrypting/decrypting/signing).  Also, the keys I generate work fine if I use them directly with ssh, and they work properly if I run the `ssh-agent` that came with openssh.

The documentation says that `ssh-add` should add keys to `~/.gnupg/sshcontrol`, but obviously nothing is happening.

My question:  What's the easiest way to load a key generated by openssh's `ssh-keygen` into `gpg-agent`, and can someone please cut and paste a terminal session showing how this works?

Comment: The accepted answer helped me, thanks for raising this question. This happens every now and then to me, is there any permanent solution?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The answer was apparently to run:

```
echo UPDATESTARTUPTTY | gpg-connect-agent
```

I have no idea why the pinentry program worked fine for other uses such as decrypting files, but didn't work for `ssh-add`.

While this now works, it also makes a copy of the ssh private key that doesn't show up under `gpg -Kv`, and furthermore doesn't seem to allow you to change the passphrase on your private key (since you can't edit it with `--edit-key`).  Basically I'm pretty unhappy with the way `gpg-agent` provides low visibility into where your secrets are being copied.  If you hit this question because you hoped `gpg-agent` might be a better alternative to `ssh-agent`,  then I'd encourage you to stick to `ssh-agent` instead of trying out my answer.  The main reason to prefer `gpg-agent` is if you need to for smart-card use.

Comment: Where did you find this answer? It works great!

Comment: Thanks for this, worked for me. Do you run this regularly? At each boot / login? Any idea regarding a "proper" fix?

Comment: See [gpg agent-options manual](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Options.html)

Comment: It is possible to find the ssh-add:ed keys out and change their password, only it's a bit of a hassle: https://blogs.gentoo.org/marecki/2017/03/17/changing-the-passphrase-for-ssh-keys-in-gpg-agent/

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem was the pinentry program used. I was using pinentry-emacs. It seems it doesn't handle the dual text field entry window prompt that `ssh-add` triggers when used with gpg-agent.

Removing pinentry-emacs and installing the GTK pinentry solved the problem here.

Comment: This finally solved my problem after finding a bunch of sources that told me to update the startup tty.